# Laravel many to many relationship returning empty array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the results using laravel many to many relationship but the query is generating wrong therefore it return empty array.

`$user->survey()->get()` is returning empty array.
`$user->survey()->toSql()` is returning wrong query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `survey`
INNER JOIN `survey_user` ON `survey`.`id` = `survey_user`.`survey_id`
WHERE
    `survey_user`.`user_id` IS NULL
```

Here, in the end, the user_id should not be null.

Migration for the survey pivot table:

```
Schema::create('survey_user',  function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('survey_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('status', 50)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('survey_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->on('users')->references('id');
    $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('survey')
          ->onDelete('cascade')
          ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

here are the two relation:

```
public function survey() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey::class, 'survey_user')
                ->withPivot('status')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'survey_user')
                ->withPivot('status')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I'm just trying to get all the users who have survey assigned in their pivot.

```
$user = new User();
var_dump($user->survey()->get());
```

Comment: can you please add more code to your question ?

Comment: May be it depends from order of calling methods, try this one `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

Comment: @potiev No, unfortunately, that was not the case. I changed the migration still the issue is same

Comment: well obviously it has null in the query, you initialized a user without an ID? new User() won't save one to the database

Comment: Why do you feel that `$user->survey()->toSql()` is returning the wrong query? Do you definitely have data in the database?

Comment: Yup I have data in database @Rwd.
when I remove `survey_user.user_id IS NULL` from the query it works but with the relation is not working

Comment: `new User()` will just create an empty User model which is why it's saying  `id IS NULL` because it hasn't actually got a User. Just to clarify are you wanting to get all users that have surveys or all surveys that have users?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to get all the users which have assigned survey
@Rwd

Comment: Ok. The answer below will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just trying to get all the users who have survey assigned in their pivot.

To get all Users where the `survey` relationship exists, your code would look like this:

```php
$users = User::has('survey')->get();
```

If you need the `survey` relationship loaded on the models when you use them, then add `with()` to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship:

```php
$users = User::has('survey')
             ->with('survey')
             ->get();
```

> Here, in the end, the user_id should not be null.

The reason it was searching with a null user id is because you are searching with a `new User` instance that hasn't been saved to the database. This is your code with the problem:

```
$user = new User();
var_dump($user->survey()->get());
```

Since `$user` is a new object that hasn't been saved to the database it doesn't have an id. When you call `$user->survey()` it builds a query to search `survey_user` where the user id is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is cleared beautifully about getting results from pivot :)